# How to ensure that .nonzero() returns one element tensor?

Tags: python, torch, stable-diffusion

[Edited to include the original source code]

I try to run the code that I found here:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1roZqqhsdpCXZr8kgV_Bx_ABVBPgea3lX?usp=sharing
(linked from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lz30by8-sU)

```
!pip install transformers diffusers lpips accelerate
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()

import torch
from transformers import CLIPTextModel, CLIPTokenizer
from diffusers import AutoencoderKL, UNet2DConditionModel, LMSDiscreteScheduler
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from torch import autocast
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy
from torchvision import transforms as tfms

# For video display:
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode

# Set device
torch_device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# Load the autoencoder model which will be used to decode the latents into image space. 
vae = AutoencoderKL.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", subfolder="vae", use_auth_token=True)

# Load the tokenizer and text encoder to tokenize and encode the text. 
tokenizer = CLIPTokenizer.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-large-patch14")
text_encoder = CLIPTextModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-large-patch14")

# The UNet model for generating the latents.
unet = UNet2DConditionModel.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", subfolder="unet", use_auth_token=True)

# The noise scheduler
scheduler = LMSDiscreteScheduler(beta_start=0.00085, beta_end=0.012, beta_schedule="scaled_linear", num_train_timesteps=1000)

# To the GPU we go!
vae = vae.to(torch_device)
text_encoder = text_encoder.to(torch_device)
unet = unet.to(torch_device)

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

prompt = ["A digital illustration of a steampunk computer laboratory with clockwork machines, 4k, detailed, trending in artstation, fantasy vivid colors"]
height = 512
width = 768
num_inference_steps = 50
guidance_scale = 7.5
generator = torch.manual_seed(4)
batch_size = 1

# Prep text 
text_input = tokenizer(prompt, padding="max_length", max_length=tokenizer.model_max_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
  text_embeddings = text_encoder(text_input.input_ids.to(torch_device))[0]
max_length = text_input.input_ids.shape[-1]
uncond_input = tokenizer(
    [""] * batch_size, padding="max_length", max_length=max_length, return_tensors="pt"
)
with torch.no_grad():
  uncond_embeddings = text_encoder(uncond_input.input_ids.to(torch_device))[0] 
text_embeddings = torch.cat([uncond_embeddings, text_embeddings])

# Prep Scheduler
scheduler.set_timesteps(num_inference_steps)

# Prep latents
latents = torch.randn(
(batch_size, unet.in_channels, height // 8, width // 8),
generator=generator,
)

latents = latents.to(torch_device)
latents = latents * scheduler.sigmas[0] # Need to scale to match k

    # Loop
with autocast("cuda"):
    for i, t in tqdm(enumerate(scheduler.timesteps)):
        # expand the latents if we are doing classifier-free guidance to avoid doing two forward passes.
        latent_model_input = torch.cat([latents] * 2)
        sigma = scheduler.sigmas[i]
        latent_model_input = latent_model_input / ((sigma**2 + 1) ** 0.5)

        # predict the noise residual
        with torch.no_grad():
            noise_pred = unet(latent_model_input, t, encoder_hidden_states=text_embeddings)["sample"]

        # perform guidance
        noise_pred_uncond, noise_pred_text = noise_pred.chunk(2)
        noise_pred = noise_pred_uncond + guidance_scale * (noise_pred_text - noise_pred_uncond)

        # compute the previous noisy sample x_t -> x_t-1
        latents = scheduler.step(noise_pred, i, latents)["prev_sample"]

# scale and decode the image latents with vae
latents = 1 / 0.18215 * latents

with torch.no_grad():
    image = vae.decode(latents)

# Display
image = (image / 2 + 0.5).clamp(0, 1)
image = image.detach().cpu().permute(0, 2, 3, 1).numpy()
images = (image * 255).round().astype("uint8")
pil_images = [Image.fromarray(image) for image in images]
pil_images[0]
```

However, I run into the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-36-0fa46b18e9c1> in <module>
     48 
     49         # compute the previous noisy sample x_t -> x_t-1
---> 50         latents = scheduler.step(noise_pred, i, latents)["prev_sample"]
     51 
     52 # scale and decode the image latents with vae

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_lms_discrete.py in step(self, model_output, timestep, sample, order, return_dict)
    216             timestep = timestep.to(self.timesteps.device)
    217 
--> 218         step_index = (self.timesteps == timestep).nonzero().item()
    219         sigma = self.sigmas[step_index]
    220 

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

This error occurs only during the 2nd iteration of the loop. The first iteration runs through smoothly.

I printed the involved variables (noise_pred, i, latents) and their respective dimensions. They have the same dimensions during the first and second iteration.

Since I run it on Colab, I don't have direct access to the underlying code in scheduling_lms_discrete.py

What can I do to avoid this error?
Has it something to do with the versioning of python or torch?
(current version: python==3.8.16. torch==1.13.0+cu116)

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code in the question itself, not as a link to an external resource. Links break over time. Post the code as a [mre] as formatted text, not an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `t` instead of `i` for the `scheduler.step` param:

```
latents = scheduler.step(noise_pred, t, latents)["prev_sample"]
```